# How to fit a a tag in a li or button tag?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

My goal is to fit a `a` tag inside a `li` or `button` tag. So information will show on the left side and the button will be on the right side. I tried attempting this by just wrapping  the `a` tag with a `<li>`, however it did not solve the issue. I am not sure where the problem occurs. Any help will be appreciated.

**Code:**

```
    <div class="list-group" id="myList">
        <div th:each="ary2 : ${ary2}">
            <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action dataObj" th:text="${ary2.mAppName}"/>
                <a th:href="@{/findOne/(appcode=${ary2.mAppCode})}" >View</a>
            </li>
        </div> 
    </div>
```

**Updated:**

```
                      <div>
                        <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action dataObj">Customer Engagement Platform</li>
                      </div>
                      <div>
                        <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action dataObj">Route Target Worksheet</li>
                      </div>
                      <div>
                        <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action dataObj">Crisis Management</li>
                      </div>
                      <div>
                        <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action dataObj">EPIC - Empowered to Positively Impact our Customers</li>
                      </div>
                      <div>
                        <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action dataObj">Germany Brokerage System Redesign</li>
                      </div>
                      <div>
                        <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action dataObj">UPS Pickup Point Management Tool</li>
                      </div>
                      <div>
                        <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action dataObj">PE - Small Sort Label Applicator Weighing</li>
                      </div>
```

This is the result I now get. As you can see it fills the `li` tags but, I don't now where the `a` tag went.

Comment: The trailing forward slash "/" in `<li … />` is junk. LI tags aren't self–closing (though the closing tag is optional) and the HTML tags that are don't need the trailing slash.

Comment: @RobG I made an update to my code with the result after applying your fix. It still didn't seem to change the error I was getting.

Comment: It won't fix the error, hence it's a comment, not an answer. :-) An HTML parser shouldn't care, an XML parser might be flummoxed.

Comment: You are doing it wrong. `li` can only be a child of `ol`, `ul`, or `menu`

Comment: @mahan is wrong. While ```li``` is supposed to be a child element of ```ol```, ```ul``` or ```menu```, it does not mean it will not render in the DOM. 

Your issue is probably with the loop function of your code

Comment: @Altair312 I meant it is invlaid to use `li` inside another elemenet except `ol`, `ul`, or `menu`. I agree with you it will be rendered even if you use.